# How to format time in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, date-formatting

I am using Java and Spring MVC. I  want to  remove last three zeroes of time value. I have put circle arrow head what I want remove.

```
<tr data-level="1">
    <td><a href="http://localhost:8080/controller/resources/details.jsp">${rs.releaseName}</a></td>
    <td>${rs.orcleCode}</td>
    <td>${rs.status}</td>
    <td>${rs.prodDate}</td>
    <td>${rs.staging}</td>
    <td>${rs.cabCall}</td>
    <td>${rs.rrr}</td>
    <td>${rs.remarks}</td>
    <td style="display: none">${rs.releaseID}</td>
```

Comment: ohh..i upload image..but it was failed..it is  like this ..out put is 

2013-11-15 10:35:00.0 i want trim last 3 zerose (00.0 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing it this way:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<fmt:formatDate value="${rs.prodDate}" pattern="MM.dd.yyyy" />
//or any other patter you need
```

Comment: then what libraries i want to  import in jsp

Comment: <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>..i used those lib..maxz..it is working..thanks dude....